# Java FX Scene Builder: Handling Multiple mouseClick() events from different source objects

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm new to java FX and especially new to scene builder. I have a small app that calculates grades based on weight. I added a menu bar to it, but Scene Builder will only let me bind a `mouseClick()` on event. The issue is, I already have a calculate button (which calculates the grade) tied to this event. I would like my `MenuItem` to open a dialog box I created when clicked.

Here is my current attempt at getting the method to work:

```
@FXML
    public void mouseClick(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
    {
        if (mouseEvent.getSource().equals(calcBtn))
        {
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            double result = calcGrade();
            resultLbl.setText("Overall Grade: " + df.format(result) + "%");
        }
        if (mouseEvent.getSource().equals(aboutMenu))
        {
            DialogBox.showInformation("About", "Some dialog here.");
        }
    }
```

In Swing, I remember doing things like this to handle multiple source objects:

```
if (e.getSource() == menuItem)
{
    //do stuff
}
else if (e.getSource() == calculateBtn)
{
    //calculate stuff 
}
```

However this does not work, and the code for the calculate button executes regardless.

Due to the way Scene Builder ties actions to the Controller class, I am unsure how to separate the actions between these two different sources when the mouse button is clicked. When I try to tie a custom on event, Scene builder yells at me and will only allow `mouseClick()`. What would be a good solution for handling this type of situation?

Comment: in principle, the approach is correct and there are no errors in the code. and that means the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using different handler methods for both events. Furthermore the `onAction` event handlers should be used (`MenuItem`s are not `Node`s therefore cannot be sources of `MouseEvent`s):

```xml
<MenuItem text="Do Something" onAction="#doSomething" />
...
<Button text="Do something else" onAction="#doSomethingElse" />
```

```
@FXML
private void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Menu Item clicked");
}

@FXML
private void doSomethingElse() {
    System.out.println("Button clicked");
}
```

This way it's easier to maintain the code. (Imagine you need to change the implementation of the action for one of the menu items and you handle 30 of them using the same method; how long would it take you to find the correct part of your if/else if. Most IDEs support navigating to a method.)

---

If you want to stick with checking the source, you should be fine as long as the event type is assignable to the method parameter:

```xml
<MenuItem fx:id="menuItem" text="Do Something" onAction="#doSomething" />
...
<Button fx:id="button" text="Do something else" onAction="#doSomething" />
```

```
@FXML Button button;
@FXML MenuItem menuItem;

@FXML
private void doSomething(ActionEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (button == source) {
        System.out.println("button clicked");
    } else if (menuItem == source) {
        System.out.println("menu item clicked");
    }
}
```

You may need to change the parameter type of the method to `Event`, if you want to handle `MouseEvent`s and `ActionEvent`s using the same method.